# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

[image: error msg]

[In html]

```
<script src='/dist/Navi.js'></script>
if (_point === 2){
                        let options = new NaviOptions({
                            startLng: geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0],
                            startLat: geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1],
                            finishLng: geojson.features[1].geometry.coordinates[0],
                            finishLat: geojson.features[1].geometry.coordinates[1]}
                            );
                        const navi = new Navi(options);
                    }
```

I'm using external js file in html, but it has problem at js file.

I don't know, what is wrong.

If you want to see details, enter http://118.130.22.146:3000/

Could you help me?

Comment: Yeah… that's not Javascript. Looks like uncompiled Typescript.

Comment: Yeah - this is also still TypeScript `constructor(options: NaviOptions) {`
Have a look at https://adminhacks.com/typescript-compile.html

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I feel like I'm stealing from the comments already given, but I think this deserves to be an actual answer:

The "Unexpected identifier" is `type` which is not a valid javascript token.

Your "js file" appears to be instead a TypeScript file, which the browser does not understand. To run it in the browser you must compile it to JavaScript first.

Comment: I was not able to think because of lack of knowledge. Thank you